# Using CRUD in xQuery

Tags: xquery, crud

Can I use XML file as data storage, and xQuery for operations of the creation, reading, updating, and deleting data? Where can i read about it? What extension of xQuery provides CRUD operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely can.  See the [XRX Beginner's Guide](http://www.danmccreary.com/xrx/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-xrx.xhtml) for an introduction.  This guide uses the free, open source [eXist-db native XML database](http://exist-db.org/) to provide storage and retrieval, and its built-in extensions for accessing HTTP request data.  A [brief, well-illustrated slide deck on XRX and CRUDS](http://www.danmccreary.com/training/xrx/11-XRX-CRUDS.ppt) by Dan McCreary provides an overview too.

Answer (score 1):

XQuery Scripting is great for CRUB operation.
Here's an example:

```
variable $stores := doc("stores.xml")/stores;

(: Create :)
insert node <store><store-number>4</store-number><state>TX</state></store> into $stores;
(: Update :)
replace value of node $stores/store[state="TX"]/store-number with "5";
(: Delete :)
delete node $stores/store[state != "TX"];
(: Read :)
$stores
```

You can try this example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#J7reoq76cdLWeQR+MG9X0MuczwQ=

Comment: Cool page, William.  Unfortunately when I click on that link, it says there's an error in the query: "(no URI):6,1: update type error [err:XUTY0008]: target expression not a single element, attribute, text, comment, or processing instruction node."

Answer (score 0):

There are also three Wikibooks that you might find useful:

```
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XRX
```

I think that XRX is perhaps the most simple and elegant way to empower non-programmers to build complex web applications.  A good XRX framework allows anyone with knowledge of the "Path" expressions to their data (XPath) to build and maintain web apps.  No Object-Relational mapping layer is needed any more.